# how to manage tab screen and navigate page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to navigate to page when button is onpressed, there are four button made up with two rows below codes. and then I made four pages those are home, shop, wallet, people but when the button is onpressed they are not changed anything, are they something incorrect in my codes? please give me some comments for these. Thanks.

```
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {

  int currentTab = 0;
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    HomePage(),
    ShopPage(),
    PeoplePage(),
    WalletPage()
  ];
  
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  Widget currentScreen = HomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 10,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = HomePage();
                        currentTab = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.home,
                          color: currentTab == 0? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = ShopPage();
                        currentTab = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.shop,
                          color: currentTab == 1? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              //Right Tab Bar Icons
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = WalletPage();
                        currentTab = 2;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.wallet,
                          color: currentTab == 2? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = PeoplePage();
                        currentTab = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.people,
                          color: currentTab == 3? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: code is incomplete add body (pages)

Answer (score 0):

The state of the currentScreen is store inside your _BottomBarState,
and the `setState()` method will only change the sub widget tree form the place where you call it.

You can read this official tutorial of [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) to understand the concept.  [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) is the way I personally recommend.

Or if you just want a simple solution,

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  late PageController pCtrl;
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pCtrl = PageController(initialPage: currentIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pCtrl.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("app"),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: pCtrl,
        children: const [
          NewsBody(),
          Posts(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.newspaper), label: "News"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.podcasts), label: "Posts"),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
          pCtrl.jumpToPage(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```